# IOS6, MPMoivePlayerViewController and device orientation

Tags: ios, ios5, video, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

My project set supported interface orientations to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait.

When I use presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated: popup an MPMoivePlayerViewController, on IOS5 when I turn device, the controller will do auto orientation rotation, but on IOS6 it is always at portrait direction.

How can I make it act as IOS5?

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed the way orientations are handle in iOS 6:

> #### Controlling What Interface Orientations Are Supported (iOS 6)
>
> When UIKit receives an orientation notification, it uses the
>   UIApplication object and the root view controller to determine whether
>   the new orientation is allowed. If both objects agree that the new
>   orientation is supported, then the user interface is rotated to the
>   new orientation. Otherwise the device orientation is ignored.
>
> When a view controller is presented over the root view controller, the
>   system behavior changes in two ways. First, the presented view
>   controller is used instead of the root view controller when
>   determining whether an orientation is supported. Second, the presented
>   view controller can also provide a preferred orientation. If the view
>   controller is presented full screen, the user interface is presented
>   in the preferred orientation. The user is expected to see that the
>   orientation is different from the device orientation and rotate the
>   device. A preferred orientation is most often used when the content
>   must be presented in the new orientation.

So if your application is set to allow only portrait mode, you'll never get into landscape mode regardless of what any controller 'sais'.

See [Controlling What Interface Orientations Are Supported (iOS 6)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW1) for more information.